# Вывести значение из БД для id

Tags: php, joomla

Существует таблица prefix_table1 в которой имеются столбцы:
'resourceId' 'resourceType' 'filename'
Также существует еще одна таблица prefix_table2 в которой имеются столбцы, один из которых 
'id'

Значение ячейки из первой таблицы 'resourceId' - соответствует значению ячейки во второй таблице 'id' - это номер статьи

вопрос как подставить 'значение filename' для данного 'resourceId' в фрагмент кода ниже. То есть подставить имя файла для текущей статьи.

```
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root(true).'/items/cache/'.'значение filename'.'_XL.jpg'; ?>" />
```

Спасибо